# Does every ordered-union coideal contain an ordered-union ultrafilter?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, infinite-combinatorics

$\newcommand{\FU}{\operatorname{FU}}$
$\newcommand{\H}{\mathcal{H}}$
Recall that an *ordered-union ultrafilter* is an ultrafilter on $\omega$ with a base of sets of the form $\FU(A)$. Here, $A = \{a_0,a_1,\dots\}$ is such that $a_i$ is a finite subset of $\omega$ for all $i$, and $\max(a_i) < \min(a_{i+1})$, and $\FU(A)$ is the set of all finite unions of elements in $A$.

Let's define a similar notion for coideals: Call a coideal $\H$ an *ordered-union coideal* if it has a base of sets of the form $\FU(A)$. That is, for every $X \in \H$, there exists a $Y \in \H$ such that $Y \subseteq X$ and $Y = \FU(A)$ for some $A$ of the form above.

My question is as follows:

> (Under suitable set-theoretic assumptions) Does every ordered-union coideal contain an ordered-union ultrafilter?

I am particular interested in the case where we assume either $\mathsf{CH}$ or $\mathsf{MA}$. I doubt that large cardinal hypotheses would be helpful, but if they do I do not want to go higher than an inaccessible.

Some important remarks:

- The existence of an ordered-union ultrafilter is not provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Blass showed in [1] that $\mathsf{CH}$ or $\mathsf{MA}$ implies the existence of an ordered-union ultrafilter, while Blass and Hindman showed in [2] that the existence of an ordered-union ultrafilter implies the existence of a selective ultrafilter. Therefore, the existence of ordered-union ultrafilter is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.
- Hindman's theorem shows that $[\omega]^\omega$ is an ordered-union coideal. Consequently, a positive answer to my question is not provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.
- By repeating the argument in [1], we can show that an ordered-union coideal satisfying some kind of selectivity property would contain an ordered-union ultrafilter. This is not what I'm looking for - I wish to know if *every* ordered-union coideal contains an ordered-union ultrafilter.

References:

1. Blass, A., *Ultrafilters related to Hindman’s finite-unions theorem and its extensions*. Contemporary Mathematics, 65(1987), 90–124.
2. Blass, A., and Hindman, N. *On strongly summable ultrafilters and union ultrafilters.* Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 304, no. 1 (1987): 83–99.

Comment: What is the situation with the analogous question using Ramsey ultrafilters and what I guess would be called "Ramsey co-ideals" under CH or MA?  Is this known?

Comment: @ToddEisworth yes, in Mathias' *Happy families* he proved that under $\mathsf{CH}$, every selective coideal contains a selective ultrafilter.